# Close previous page in phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am new in phonegap. How can I close previous page in phonegap. For example I have two pages(page1 and page2). I want to close page1 after go to page2. How can I do this.? Please help.
Thank you

Comment: you should build singlepage apps and you dont 'close' previous page if you want to do it this way. do you close a webpage on clicking a link?

Comment: Are you using any framework? How you are going to the page2? Show the code.

Answer (score 1):

If you navigate from one HTML page to another in Cordova/PhoneGap you don't have to close previous page, since it will be automatically disposed for you by the browser.

If you are using some other technology like jQuery Mobile/Sencha Touch/Kendo UI or other, please consult documentation for corresponding product how to accomplish desired task.